# Improving Neo4j's write performance

Tags: performance, neo4j

I'm testing neo4j to see how it performs against traditional RDBMSs (right now I'm comparing it to PostgreSQL). And as for the testbed, I'm using the sample database [found here](http://linux.dell.com/dvdstore/2011-12-01/).

The sample database has 10k product records within 16 categories. I'm trying to store these data into the databases with structures as close to each other as possible. Of course, since neo4j is a graph database and PostgreSQL is an RDBMS, the two structures can not be identical.

I'm not going to get into too much detail, I'll just give sample queries showing how I insert data into each database:

```
MATCH (cr:Category:Revision) where cr.id = ?
CREATE (pe:Data:Entity:Product)-[:RevisionOf]->(pr:Data:Revision:Active:Latest:Product{title: "?", actor: "?", price: ?, special: "?"})-[:ProductCategory]->(cw:Data:Category:Wrapper)<-[:Wrapper]-(cr)
```

And

```
INSERT INTO performance.entity (entity_id, type) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Product')
INSERT INTO performance.revision (revision_id, entity_id, user_id, create_date, fields) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, 0, DEFAULT, ?)
INSERT INTO performance.relation (source_id, destination_id, relation) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant or not, but I'm using a PHP script for record insertion and then I'll measure how long the process takes. Also, I'm using the [neo4j bolt driver](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client) which is implemented by graphaware in PHP.

After some test runs, on average it takes like **2.5ms** to insert each product (the three insert SQL) while it takes **11ms** to execute a single Cypher query (which inserts 3 nodes with one shot). So neo4j is four times slower than PostgreSQL. And this size of data is small enough to rule out memory size impact and limitation on the number of open files (`ulimit`) for neo4j (as it is said they are parameters to look into for [improving its performance](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/)). The `data` folder for neo4j is less than 25MB after the whole data is imported.

So my question is, does anyone have any tip on how to improve neo4j's write performance?

**[UPDATE]**

So, I gave it a second try. This time I tried to eliminate any extra index or whatever that might impose extra work on Neo4j. Right now, I've got only one constraint on `:Data(id)` which actually helps the performance (I've tested it).

The results of my latest test show that the creation of three nodes and matching one takes around **10.5ms**, more or less like before. This is compared to Postgres' results in which it takes **2.5ms** to insert three records (no `SELECT`).

So to make things even, I changed the Cypher command to this:

```
CREATE (pe:Data:Entity:Product)-[:RevisionOf]->(pr:Data:Revision:Active:Latest:Product{title: "?", actor: "?", price: ?, special: "?"})-[:ProductCategory]->(cw:Data:Category:Wrapper)
```

As you can see, this version has no `MATCH` statement, making it as close as possible to Postgres equivalent. This time, having only three nodes created per each request, it still takes **9.5ms**.

So my question is still valid, how to improve Neo4j's write performance?

**[UPDATE]**

At this point, I'm sure that I've tested all the scenarios that I could think of. I've tested three more scenarios:

First, I've removed the index altogether and inserted three connected nodes per request:

```
CREATE (pe:Data:Entity:Product)-[:RevisionOf]->(pr:Data:Revision:Active:Latest:Product{title: "?", actor: "?", price: ?, special: "?"})-[:ProductCategory]->(cw:Data:Category:Wrapper)
```

In this scenario, each request takes around **9.1ms**.

As for the second scenario, I removed the labels too (except one):

```
CREATE (pe:Data)-[:RevisionOf]->(pr:Data{title: "?", actor: "?", price: ?, special: "?"})-[:ProductCategory]->(cw:Data)
```

In the second scenario, each request takes around **8ms**.

For the last scenario I, I stripped down all the nodes from data:

```
CREATE (pe:Data)-[:RevisionOf]->(pr:Data)-[:ProductCategory]->(cw:Data)
```

Now, each request takes like **5.9ms** to complete. Even though all these scenarios are useless in practice, yet they don't get close to Postgres' performance. Considering that for Postgres, I send three requests and I haven't done any optimization for it.

Should I just give up on Neo4j?

Comment: Assumption : you've got a unique constraint or index on cr.id ? Observation : you're not doing 3 "inserts" in Neo4j, you're doing six "inserts". Remember that those relationships are also "first class citizens" (and could potentially also have properties). So some impact is to be expected ...

Comment: I get your point and I do have an index on `id`. But I've also got indices on `entity_id`, 'revision_id` and `source_id`, `destination_id`. My point is, I think these two are more or less comparable. For one thing, the Neo4j scenario sends one request per record while PostgreSQL sends three!

Comment: Really ? Actually you're writing (for Neo4j, simplified, not actual code) :
MATCH (cr), CREATE(pe), CREATE(pr), CREATE(cw), CREATE [:RevisionOf], CREATE [:ProductCategory], CREATE [:Wrapper].  You are not doing a SELECT on PostgreSQL and very likely all labels have a unique constraint (matching the indexes you mention). And we're comparing one transaction against one transaction (you're not doing commits between your inserts). Write out the discrete statements for Neo4j and you'll see you're not comparing the same thing.

Comment: ... and granted, that is mainly due to the difference of the databasestructure. You are bound to lose a bit in writes, you will gain a bit in reads when you're doing joins (and you gain massively as the number of joins goes up). And I leave the possibility open that your Neo4j statements can be made more performant. But you're not really comparing the same thing.

Comment: You should also use parameters, and batch updates in larger transactions. Can you also share your graph data model which looks much more complex and different than the relational one? It doesn't even use the same fields?

Comment: I shall provide you with guys with more info once I'm back from vacation. Thanks.

Comment: For my project I've decided to recreate neo4j database on each update. Importing through csv has performance about 100 million in 3 minutes. I think insert speed is not important, but lookup speed is everything and neo4j shines here.